# Async WCF call not firing in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, wcf-data-services

Basically, I'm using a WCF call in my phone app to retrieve a password, however it doesn't fire when I want it to, and I'm unsure where to put the call.

Essentially, I want the app to call the code like this

```
  Client.GetPassWordByNameAsync(user);
        Client.GetPassWordByNameCompleted += new EventHandler<GetPassWordByNameCompletedEventArgs>(Client_GetPassWordByNameCompleted);


        if(EnteredPassword == password)
        {
            isAuthenticated = true;
        }
```

As when the user presses the login button, it should call the service, grab the password, and compare however, it just skips over the code and returns null.

this is the completed method

```
   void Client_GetPassWordByNameCompleted(object sender, GetPassWordByNameCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                password = e.Result;
            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Having a look to your code, I see, in the one hand, that you subsbcribe to GetPassWordByNameCompleted event after you have called the method. In the other hand, you don't wait until you get the response to compare the returned value. The following code should work:

```
Client.GetPassWordByNameCompleted += ((s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        password = e.Result;
        if(EnteredPassword == password)
        {
                isAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }
});
Client.GetPassWordByNameAsync(user);
```

Or if you prefer to have the event handler in a different method, first subscribe to the event:

```
    Client.GetPassWordByNameCompleted += new EventHandler<GetPassWordByNameCompletedEventArgs>(Client_GetPassWordByNameCompleted);
    Client.GetPassWordByNameAsync(user);
```

And do whatever you want with the result, once you have obtained it:

```
void Client_GetPassWordByNameCompleted(object sender, GetPassWordByNameCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        password = e.Result;
        if(EnteredPassword == password)
        {
            isAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually solved the problem by putting the checks that needed to be done after ( because it was Async it was skipping to these straight away) in the completed method, and it works fine. However the peoblem for the null responses was due to the result returning a serialisation error. But thanks for your help.